# Is this site's colour scheme readable?

Tags: color, style, color-scheme

Having realised that I am not very good at identifying whether a site works and is readable, can I ask for comments on [this site](http://steveclough.eweb702.discountasp.net/Default.aspx)'s colour scheme, which is entirely under my control. I have tried to go for a deliberately minimalist style, and not for prettiness.

[image]

[EDIT] For any future readers, I have updated this with some of the recommendations

Comment: With a bad 3-day migraine I am having trouble with the serif font and the text size on some pages, but the colours look fine to me.

Comment: Colors are fine but typography & styling are horrible (plus the JS-animated "intro").

Comment: Any suggestion in the "intro" - it sort of matches what I want to do, but if it goes down badly, I will change it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason there are 3 different fonts (header, intro, body) going on here? As stated, small serifs on a screen are bad for readability, but in most successful minimalist designs I've seen, there's one font (for simplicity/consistency's sake)

Comment: I don't think this is a good question.  It's not specific - while the title refers to the site's colour scheme, the question is basically asking for a critique.

Comment: I was specifically asking for colours, because that is what I have struggled with before. Other comments are welcome.

Comment: I think there are much bigger issues to deal with than it being green--in other words, at this point, the color is almost moot. There are issues of scale, typography, layout, flow, etc. that need to be dealt with first.

Comment: But the question raised specifically was readability. Other stuff I have others looking at. But I know I can come here and people won't spare me. Which is probably good.

Comment: @codeinthehole - if I was after a full critique, I would have provided more information about the clientelle, expectations etc. Most of this I can sort myself, and with others who are looking at it, but I have been made aware that I don't always spot colour.readability issues.

Comment: "But the question raised specifically was readability" but design can't be easily evaluated piecemeal. Everything has to work with everything else.

Comment: @DA01 - yes, but this was a specific question I was raising on this site. Your comment could apply to a lot of questions here. And it has produced some good answers serving as guidelines to readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personal opinion:

- The font size is a bit small
- The serif font isn't the best for readability
- Not sure about the colour contrast of some of the selected states/hover of the menu options
- Centrally justified text isn't great for readability either

Just checked the green text for colour contrast and it seems to pass WCAG AA guidelines

Comment: The colours are intended to be close to black on white, but just off, so it is not so straining. The hover states I am not certain of either.

Comment: This is a very correct answer.

Comment: Does this answer OP's "I was specifically asking for (about) colours"?

Comment: It was readability - colours being my previous downfall. Marked as accepted, because it covers most of the things I will be changing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the colors are neither appropriate nor comfortable.

For the links as well as the titles, I would go with a dark blue/ dark brown, closer to but clearly distinguishable from black. Green generally does not render well with text.

Furthermore, it is better to use a consistent color scheme with just one color for the menu and one for the titles.

I presume you will be using color (not black) for the body of the text as well. In that case, grey or dark blue should be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO menus should not change in size when you hover over it, for me it's really annoying because I want menus to be fixed in size, but change its color for instance.

site title is somehow very very big, you have to concentrate to understand what is it telling you.

site title's font family is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're achieving the minimal look by readability is affected by your color scheme, but I do find that the font-size and misalignment of the paragraphs is a bigger problem. Long centered lines of text are hard to follow, try maybe to increase the font size and reduce number of words per line.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into other details I would just tell how to check if the font contrast is readable or not.

Go to [Contrast Checker](http://contrastchecker.com/), here Foreground is your text color and background is well... background color(white in your case).

The site uses WCAG guideline to judge the same.